# Why WebView content size is zero even if it's not empty?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I'm trying to load HTML in `viewDidLoad` with:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(myHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

and check the size:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print(webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
}
```

I get `0.0` even my HTML is not empty. What is wrong here, any ideas? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you set the webView frame size?